# What does the [-] symbol mean in satellite names?

Tags: artificial-satellite, satellite-flare

Some satellites in the databases have this "[-]" mark at the end. For example "IRIDIUM 39 [-]" and "GLOBALSTAR M038 [-]", which in databases like [www.space-track.org](http://www.space-track.org) or the ones managed by [satview.org](http://www.satview.org/?versao=classica&lang=us&sat_id=25042U) and [celestrack](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/iridium.txt) are presented with that symbol.

What does it mean? Does it have something to do with flaring?

Comment: +1 What I did find are that other identifiers, "[+]", "[P]", "[B]", and "[S]" occur as well as "[-]". It doesn't seem to be standard, and it's almost ungoogleable, but it doesn't seem to be explained anywhere—and in particular not on the celestrack website. My suggestion would be to contact the author of that site and just ask; he seems open to questions. Then report back here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[-]` means that the satellite is nonoperational.  It's one of the eight ["Operational Status Codes"](https://celestrak.org/satcat/status.php).

```
+   Operational
-   Nonoperational
P   Partially Operational
B   Backup/Standby
S   Spare
X   Extended Mission
D   Decayed
?   Unknown
```

More about the SATCAT format is documented [here](https://celestrak.org/satcat/satcat-format.php).

Comment: You are a wonderfull person. Thank you so much